# How to change the centering-changing-point of the gallery?

Tags: android

I built a gallery. The centered image is scaled up. I did this by extending from gallery and overwriting getChildStaticTransformation. There I  modified the camera. It zooms in when the image is close to the center point.

Problem: the centering item (from *getSelectedItem()*) changes a bit too late. sometimes the side elements that are smaller than the next coming get re-centered.

Is there any way to tell the gallery when it has tochanng to its neighbor?

Thank you so far.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this actually depends on the spacings set by setSpacing. If this paramter is 0 the gallery centers correctly as I want.

Problem: the Images spacing are to big then.

Is there a way to minimize the spacings without setSpacing in an artificial way?

Thanks